# Cant get my light sequence to stay on by pushing a button once using Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, project

Hi so my issue is i am trying to start my light sequence after i have pushed a pushbutton. I get that to work however the light sequence only stays on if i have the button held down. I want it so that once the button is pushed once it will stay on for one sequence.

The reason why i see this happen is because there is a command that is constantly updating for new inputs and by having a push button input it halts the command from updating until pushed. the command    if (ScrollingMsg.UpdateText() == -1) is where the issue lies i believe as it needs to be constantly updated. My code is below many thanks.

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#include <LEDMatrix.h>
#include <LEDText.h>
#include <FontMatrise.h>



#define LED_PIN        6
#define COLOR_ORDER    GRB
#define CHIPSET        WS2812B

#define MATRIX_WIDTH   -38
#define MATRIX_HEIGHT  8
#define MATRIX_TYPE    VERTICAL_ZIGZAG_MATRIX
int buttonPin;
cLEDMatrix<MATRIX_WIDTH, MATRIX_HEIGHT, MATRIX_TYPE> leds;

cLEDText ScrollingMsg;

const unsigned char TxtDemo[] = {EFFECT_RGB_CV "\x218\x56\x45\x136\x78\x12" EFFECT_FRAME_RATE "\x02" EFFECT_SCROLL_LEFT "  4 " 
                       EFFECT_CHAR_UP "  LEFT"
                          EFFECT_SCROLL_LEFT "4 " 

                                   };

void setup()
{

  FastLED.addLeds<CHIPSET, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds[0], leds.Size());
  Serial.begin(9600);
  buttonPin = 10; //whatever pin your button is plugged into
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  FastLED.setBrightness(64);


  FastLED.clear(true);
  delay(500);
  FastLED.show();

  ScrollingMsg.SetFont(MatriseFontData);
  ScrollingMsg.Init(&leds, leds.Width(), ScrollingMsg.FontHeight() + 1, 0, 0);
  ScrollingMsg.SetText((unsigned char *)TxtDemo, sizeof(TxtDemo) - 1);
  ScrollingMsg.SetTextColrOptions(COLR_RGB | COLR_SINGLE, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff);

}


void loop()
{


  if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) {
    runner();
  }
}




int runner() {

        if (ScrollingMsg.UpdateText() == -1)
    ScrollingMsg.SetText((unsigned char *)TxtDemo, sizeof(TxtDemo) - 1);

  else
    FastLED.show();

  delay(10);



}
```

Comment: Instead of having `runner()` be dependent on whether a button is pressed or not, have `runner()` be dependent on whether you're in the `do_runner` state (you can use a `bool do_runner` for this). Then, in your loop, pressing the button doesn't enter the `runner()` function, it sets the `do_runner` state. Once your `runner()` logic has finished (whatever finished means to you) set `do_runner` back to `false`. This is a simple *state machine*. You should look up that term if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: HI im a bit confused on the bool do_runner. I have created bool do_runner which is set to true if the button is pushed and then have an else statement setting it to false. I have then another if statement saying if do_runner is true execute runner but now it is always on. I dont think im following what you mean or im just coding it wrong.

Comment: Was the information you found on state machines helpful?

Comment: Yea it was. I will implement it later

Comment: The solution to your problem is to implement a state machine now. I don't know what else to tell you. If you only have two states (the light should be blinking vs the light shouldn't be blinking) you can represent this with boolean.

Comment: Ok just got it thanks for your help!

Comment: Beside understanding how to toggle a Boolean variable you will also have to learn how to debounce a button. Google it.

Comment: yep got the debounce too thanks